# Is it faster to insert a contiguous series of numbers or random numbers into a SQLite btree-index

Tags: b-tree

Let's say we have a large dataset that has to get into the SQLite database, 250 million items. Let's say the table is

```
          create table foo (myInt integer, name text)
```

and myInt is indexed *but is not unique*.  There's no primary key.

The values are between 1 and 250000000 and duplicates are very very rare but not impossible. That is intentional/by design.

Given the way the b-tree algorithms work (and ignoring other factors) which is the faster insert, and why?

```
        (a) dataset is first sorted on myInt column (ascending or descending) and the data
        rows are then inserted in their pre-sorted order into SQLite
        (b) dataset is inserted in a totally random order
```

Comment: One sure-fire way to find out is to just try it.

Comment: I want to understand why. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely (a).
Random insertion in a btree is much slower.